# RGB transparent color value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, syntax

I've got a script that changes some CSS on scroll and it currently uses a hex value for a color. I need to switch the #ffffff to rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) I think the .6 messes up the syntax but I don't know how to make it right.

```
var $mainlogo = jQuery('#mainlogo');
var $menuback = jQuery('.x-navbar');
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
    $mainlogo.css({display: jQuery(this).scrollTop()>170 ? "block":"none"});
$menuback.css({background: jQuery(this).scrollTop()>170 ? "#ffffff":"none"});
});
```

Comment: `.css({background:"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)"});` worked fine for me, what problems are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$menuback.css({background: jQuery(this).scrollTop()>170 ? "rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.6 )":"none"});
```